# Unique IDs for (Jquery) live content

Tags: php, jquery, unique

```
$("#addNewItem").on("click", function() {
    $.get('showItem.php',function(data) {
        // add new item
        $('#newItems').after(data);         
    })             
});
```

With that code I call the PHP-file as you can see. In the PHP file is a input-select that get data from a database. And there is an text-input field.
Every time the user click on the button `#addNewItem` the two inputs where created. Every click creates a new "item set". So far so good. But how can I handle it that the inputs gets unique IDs and names. So that I can give it later to a PHP form handler thats writes it to the database?

Code from the PHP-File:

```
<select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="productitem" id="productitem">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>

    <?  //foreach($stmtPL as $rowPL) {
        while($rowPRL = $stmtPRL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
            <option><? echo $rowPRL[1] . " / " . $rowPRL[2] . " / " . $rowPRL[4]; ?></option>
    <? } ?>

    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>                  
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="count">Count:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="count" name="count" value="1" maxlength="5" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Update: the JS:

```
$("#addNewItem").on("click", function() {

var count = 0;
 count++;



 $.get('chunk.showBillItem.php?zahl=' + count ,function(data) {

        // Neue Items anfügen
        $('#newItems').after(data);


     })

});
```

The count is always 1 (?)

Comment: add your php code please

Comment: Wouldn't the record IDs be generated when adding the items to the database?  It would be difficult to say the least to try to keep IDs unique if they haven't been persisted to the backing data yet, since multiple people can be using the page simultaneously.

Comment: Use a `json` response and try [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: Use array-style input names, `name=productitem[]`. Then when you submit the form, `$_POST['productitem']` will be an array of all the inputs.

Comment: That is a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: There is a DIV tag in your select tag. What is the link between the php code and js ? If you get data, get a json file, not a HTML one.
Loop through the array you get from json and generate html from these data.

Comment: That sounds good, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I figured out another problem that I run into with that stuff is that the two input-fields are, so the say, "item sets". In the select I choose the product and in input I set the count. So when I give it to a PHP handler i run in trouble what input(count) belongs to what select. My solution for that ist that I want to count how often the button is clicked and give this number to to php and generates the uniq IDs and names from that. But I stuck a litte bit with ja JS for counting. It is always 1 (see in the code above)